# Does the game from "The Game" have a name?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, video-games

In the *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episode "[The Game](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Game_(episode))", Riker's choice in shore leave company leads directly to the crew becoming addicted to a weird game in which the player needs to put discs into chutes:

[image]

[image]

(Yes, that's Ashley Judd in the first screen shot, and no, she wasn't Photoshopped in.)

Question:

**Does the game have a name?**

Comment: Bonus question: Out-of-universe, has someone made a working version of the game (minus the headset part, of course) that can actually be played on a computer or a mobile device?

Comment: Bonus question is its own question now: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93989/does-the-ktarian-game-exist-in-our-universe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A scan through [the original script](http://tng.trekcore.com/episodes/scripts/206.txt) indicates that it's just called "the game" in both the dialogue and the episode direction

> **PICARD:** *We also have an opportunity to introduce the game to Starfleet Academy.*

and

> **WESLEY'S POV - THE GAME (OPTICAL)**
>
> A view of the bridge -- with the familiar GAME OVERLAY   superimposed
>   on top. The playing field has a cone and   a disc coasting across it.
>   Picard and Beverly are   visible beyond the overlay, looking straight
>   at us.

---

The Memory Alpha wiki refers to it as the "[Ktarian Game](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ktarian_game)" (based on the race of aliens who provided it), something echoed by [this mini-documentary](http://www.startrek.com/watch_video/ktarian-game-the) on the Startrek.com website.

> "[Nothing the crew had ever encountered could have prepared them for]
>   the threat they encountered in the form of the seemingly benign
>   Ktarian Game"

[image]