# Does The Ktarian Game exist, out-of-universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, video-games

As established in this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93981/), the discs-and-chutes game from the *Star Trek: the Next Generation* episode "[The Game](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Game_(episode))" is known as **The Ktarian Game**, after the race that proliferated it as a mind-control device.

[image]

**Out-of-universe, does there exist a working version of The Ktarian Game (not necessarily including the headset part) that can actually be played on a computer or a mobile device?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes!

I am pleased to report that The Ktarian Game *does* exist on Google Glass (which is a fairly fitting homage to the original)!

The website for it is [here](https://thegameonglass.appspot.com/).  (Note: I am in no way associated with this game - just letting you know)

Comment: Amazing!  (This might actually renew my interest in Google Glass...)